# R: Importing data from several csv and including file.info to each row

Tags: r, function, file, data-binding, import

I'm parsing several csv files (+30). Each file contents several invoices an represent a claiming (all the invoices claimed on this moment).

```
 Client.Code.       Invoice     Invoice.Date  Amount
   1:      1005500 21601000209   2016-01-31 5016.00
   2:      1005500 21602000630   2016-02-29 2239.52
   3:      1004773 21603000224   2016-03-31 3993.00 
   4:      1005500 21605000350   2016-05-31 9278.00
```

I would like to import all the information of this files, and include in the matrix which contains every invoices, a column with each file `date of creation` (the origin file date of creation), because it really points the date of the action.

I'm using this code to the parsing:

```
  Claiming.files<-list.files("/path/of/my/files/2017", pattern=".csv", 
  full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

  Claiming.lines<-rbindlist(lapply(Claiming.files,function(x){read.csv(x, 
  header=1, sep=";", dec=",", na.strings="")}))
```

Then I would like the know how to introduce the date of modification of each corresponding file of "claiming files" to the rows binded in the matrix "Claiming.files"

i.e.:

```
x<-file.mtime(Claiming.files)

[1] "2017-01-16 19:51:33 CET"  "2017-01-20 13:28:36 CET"  "2017-01-23 18:57:55 CET"  "2017-02-03 12:59:49 CET"  "2017-02-06 20:05:41 CET" 
[6] "2017-02-15 14:13:56 CET"  "2017-02-20 18:05:32 CET"


Claiming.lines

 Client.Code.       Invoice     Invoice.Date  Amount  **Claiming date**
   1:      1005500 21601000209   2016-01-31 5016.00    **16/01/2017**
   2:      1005500 21602000630   2016-02-29 2239.52    **12/03/2017**
   3:      1004773 21603000224   2016-03-31 3993.00    **15/04/2017**
   4:      1005500 21605000350   2016-05-31 9278.00    **19/06/2017**
```

Can I introduce some arguments in the `function()` in order to bind the files including the date of creation of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column for mtime and then bind it to the lines output from your 
read.csv with something like this.

```
 Claiming.lines<-rbindlist(lapply(Claiming.files,function(x){
 lines <-  read.csv(x,header=1, sep=";", dec=",", na.strings="")
 mtime <-  file.info(x)$mtime
 data <-   cbind(lines, mtime)
 }))
```